# How to typeset variables and other code?

Tags: formatting

> The variance of the signal `sig3` is 43.2.

How should I typeset the above in LaTeX?

Comment: Are the four characters in `sig3` all supposed to be on one line, or is `3` to be typeset as a subscript to `sig`? And, is `sig` a (mathematical, physical, engineering) variable?

Comment: @Micro: They are supposed to be on one line. `sig3` a MATLAB variable.

Comment: In that case the answer provided by @LeoLiu should fully meet your needs. :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`\verb|sig3|` or `\texttt{sig3}` if no special characters included.

Comment: Since this is LaTeX which emphasizes semantic markup, providing a command such as ``\newcommand{\code}[1]{\texttt{#1}}`` would be a good idea so that you can easily change the appearance of all code bits in the future.

Comment: Is there any difference between the two? It seems not when I use them but just wondering

Comment: @debsim \\texttt just sets the given text to a monospaced font. \\verb sets it to a monospaced font and ignores all TeX markup. It is to typeset inline TeX code so the markup doesn't have to be escaped. The argument of \\verb is everything between the next character after the “\verb” and the next occurrence of that character.